# Is it good idea to ignore the warning message `VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews`

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am beginner in react native

I am trying to use flatList in `react native`,
The thing is that I need to use `ScrollView` and `flatList` at the same time because I am showing a lot of items.

So I write the component something like this

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';


const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const isCloseToBottom = ({layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize}) => {
  const paddingToBottom = 20;
  return (
    layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >=
    contentSize.height - paddingToBottom
  );
};

const BikeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [renderDataCount, setRenderDataCount] = useState(10);

  const bikeList = useSelector((state) => state.productReducer.bikeList);
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.token);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  

  useEffect(() => {
    LogBox.ignoreLogs(['VirtualizedLists should never be nested']);
  }, []);

  const stateChange = () => {
    setChildState(!childState);
  };

const renderItems = ({ item }) => (
    <IndividualProduct
      info={item}
      fav={true}
      stateChange={stateChange}
      setLoading={setLoading}
    />
  );

  return (
    <ScrollView
      onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => {
        if (isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {
          if (renderDataCount + 4 < bikeList.length) {
            setRenderDataCount(renderDataCount + 4);
          } else if (renderDataCount + 1 < bikeList.length) {
            setRenderDataCount(renderDataCount + 1);
          }
        }
      }}
      scrollEventThrottle={400}>
      <Loader loading={loading} />

      {bikeList.length > 1 && (
        <FlatList
          data={bikeList}
          renderItem={renderItems}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
        />
      )}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default BikeScreen;
```

So when I try to use both `ScrollView` and `flatList`
I got the error log something like this

`WARNING : VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews`

So as you can see in the code I am using useEffect hook to ignore the warning.

The thing is that the data coming from the api is `alot` numbering up to 400 items in bikelist
So I am concern about the performance issue.

What I want to know is that `Is Ignoring this warning statement` a good idea?
And is there anyway this is effecting my app performance?

Comment: Can you try to add <View> outside the <ScrollView>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://nyxo.app/fixing-virtualizedlists-should-never-be-nested-inside-plain-scrollviews

> **Why nesting VirtualizedList inside a plain ScrollView is bad?**
>
> Virtualized lists, that means  and  for
> example, are performance-optimized meaning they massively improve
> memory consumption and performance when using them to render large
> lists of content. The way this optimization works is that it only
> renders the content that is currently visible in the window, usually
> meaning the container/screen of your device. It also replaces all the
> other list items same sized blank space and renders them based on your
> scrolling position.
>
> Now If you put either of these two lists inside a ScrollView they fail
> to calculate the size of the current window and will instead try to
> render everything, possibly causing performance problems, and it will
> of course also give you the warning mentioned before.